# How to make a child element background color(transparent) to the viewport background or body tag background color

Tags: html, css

I have a following markup and i want to make the div(class child) transparent(similar to hole) which should display the background color yellow in this case. Please help me how to achive this?

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 4% 10%
}
.ancestor {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  background: Red;
}
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 190px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: Green;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<div class="ancestor">
  <!-- ancestor bgcolr red -->
  <div class="parent">
    <!-- bgcolr green -->
    <div class="child">
      <!-- bgcolr transparent -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

`
```

Comment: You'll have to make it have a color, you can't tell CSS to ignore some of the ancestors.

Comment: do u want just transperent or transperent yelow?

Comment: Actually i want to make a hole in the child element which should display the body bgcolor. don't want the parent or ancesstor bgcolor property.

Comment: You want `child` div to Ignore `parent` and `ancestor` div's BG and should show BG of Body? Then why don't you give yellow bg to 'child' div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/pEKLGj

```css
body {
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2i8QSOCJ7aKXyZb2Rn2a_r-seI_d_pCuEFDoGxyuyC1tkQIOhmRuXae05);
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 4% 10%
}
.ancestor {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  border-width: 120px 100px 10px 190px;
  background: transparent;
}
.parent {
  width: 410px;
  height: 370px;
  border: 1px solid #0c0;
  border-width: 120px 100px 10px 190px;
  background: transparent;
}
.child {
  width: 408px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="ancestor">
  <!-- ancestor bgcolr red -->
  <div class="parent">
    <!-- bgcolr green -->
    <div class="child">
      <!-- bgcolr transparent -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an SVG file with a hole in it.